# Handling failed login notifications with Spring Security 3 login handlers

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

In my application, I would like to increase a failed login attempt counter for my users and lock them when it reaches a certain attemp count using Spring Security version 3.1.4.RELEASE.

I have succcessfully implemented a simple login success notification handler that resets the counter to zero and saves this state in my database like so.

```
public class BitfoodLoginSuccessHandler extends BitfoodAuthHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest arg0,
      HttpServletResponse arg1, Authentication arg2) throws IOException,
      ServletException {

    String userName = arg2.getName();
    AppUser result = getBitfoodDao().getAuthDao().getUser(userName);

    if (result.getLoginStatus().getStatus() == UserLoginStatus.STATUS_ACTIVE) {
      result.getLoginStatus().setLoginFailCount(0);
      getBitfoodDao().getAuthDao().save(result);
    } // TODO redirect on success.
  }
}
```

However, I'm trying to figure out how to implement the opposite case in a failure event handler which is specifically, an implementation of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

```
public class BitfoodLoginFailedHandler extends BitfoodAuthHandler implements
    AuthenticationFailureHandler {

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest arg0,
      HttpServletResponse arg1, AuthenticationException arg2)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.info("???????");
    /*if (ls.getLoginFailCount() >= 3) { // TODO parameterize this value
      ls.setStatus(UserLoginStatus.STATUS_LOCKED);
    }*/
  }
}
```

I know that `org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException` offfers these two methods which could potentially provide the login information I need. Specifically, I'm trying to find out which username (if any and if it is indeed a user I have on DB) has failed the current login attempt.

[org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html)

```
AuthenticationException::getAuthentication()
AuthenticationException::getExtraInformation()
```

However, both methodds are mark as deprecated in versions 3.1.x of the API. So:

1) Is there another way I could retrieve the failed login username of the attempt using these notification handlers?

2) Should I consider using another mechanism altogether to perform this logic? If so, which alternatives does Spring Security 3 offer?

**UPDATE:** Wow, @axtavt 's answer worked and ended being up more clean than what I had in mind since I no longer have to mess with my security manager's filter configuration anymore. Nice!

Updated code:

I changed the interfaces of my custom classes:

```
public class BitfoodLoginFailedHandler extends BitfoodAuthHandler 
    implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> 

public class BitfoodLoginSuccessHandler extends BitfoodAuthHandler 
    implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>
```

I implemented the appropriate method:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event)
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event)
```

Left their bean context definitions as-is:

```
<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.bitfood.admin.auth.BitfoodLoginSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="bitfoodDao" ref="daoService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="failureHandler" class="org.bitfood.admin.auth.BitfoodLoginFailedHandler">
    <beans:property name="bitfoodDao" ref="daoService"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And Voila! Received appropriate notifications (including username data) before the request ended.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way to recieve notifications about authentication events is to [listen for `ApplicationEvent`s](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) broadcasted by Spring Security, namely, `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` and `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent`.